# Pattern match union type in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js, union-types

Using Scala.js, if I have `x: String | Int`, how do I test for its actual type? `x match { ... }` does not compile.

Answer (score 4):

Ascribe it to Any, then you can pattern match: `(x: Any) match { ... }`